# How to get the fileURL when an ACTIVE app is opened from other apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have already implemented DocumentTypes in the info.plist, and the applicationDidFinishedLaunchingWithOptions just works fine, because I can get the fileURL from the option dictionary.

My question is: when I opened my app and send it to background, and open other apps such as Safari and "Open in" a file, my app become active and is there anyway to get the fileURL from anyplace? I found that applicationDidBecomeActive has no userInfo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `application:handleOpenURL:` or `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` in your UIApplicationDelegate to get this information.